# Underline a link

Tags: css

I have a link in an html `<a>` tag.  I want to underline this link.

```
<a href="#" > Invalid </a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a class="underline"> Invalid </a>

a.underline
{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This should work!

Answer (score 2):

Mittchel is right with the CSS. However, I would advise to take a look around and see why you need to explicitly tell it to be underlined. Anchor tags should be underlined by the default stylings. So if the CSS code above does not work, take a look at the CSS being applied and make sure you have enough specificity points to overwrite the previous style.

A good beginning guide to specificity can be found here:
[Specifics on CSS Specifity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: +1 for a good point, though I would imagine it's likely to be the result of a reset.css or similar, in which case the reset style should be fairly low specificity.